# Spring Batch Job logging on completion

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch job which runs like this:

```
public void myMethod() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
    logger.log("Job Starting");

    JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
            .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .toJobParameters();

    jobLauncher.run(myJob(), param);

    logger.log("Job Finished");
}
```

This runs asynchronously by using a `TaskExecutor`. So the second `logger.log` logs immediately after the job has been called.

I want the logging to log after `myJob()` has finished.

I have tried changing the actual job to do this but this doesn't seem like the best solution. I also tried looking for methods such as `andThen` and `onComplete` but I couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at `JobExecutionListener` this allows you to do some processing before and after the job execution.

```
public class DoSomethingAroundJob implements JobExecutionListener {

  public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
      System.out.println("Called beforeJob().");
  }

  public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
      System.out.println("Called afterJob().");
  }
}
```

Then you would need to configure you Job to use this listener. For example.

```
@Bean
public Job myJob(){
    return jobs.get("myJob")           
        .listener(new DoSomethingAroundJob())          
        .build();
}
```

There would be other parts of your job, but the above just shows an example of adding a listener wit JavaConfig.

Comment: I second this answer, this is how I would implement the use case in the question.